# Simulate many android users

Tags: android, testing, load

I already have my android application and server. Now, I would like to simulate server load test with over 1,000 users. But, I do not know how to do that.

How to simulate many users that use my android application to measure the server loading.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly clear what your server does, but assuming it uses HTTP in some form, you could use [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) to simulate multiple connections.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should write a Load Test application (in any language), that connects to your Server and sends basically the same request as one of your android clients does. But this Load tester should do it 1000 times (maybe possible with multiple threads), with small time differences between the calls, so that the simulation is realistic.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate load with other means that actual devices. First find out what kind of actions clients are executing and what kind of network traffic those cause. Create a test suite with JMeter or similar and execute with expected load.